# Separate GET parameters from POST in embedded Jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I need to know wheather the parameter is GET or POST but in `handle` method `request.getParameter(name)` gives me all parameters. Is it possible to do something like `request.getGETParameter(name)` and `request.getPOSTParameter(name)` or do I have to parse raw data myself?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as GET parameters and POST parameters. GET and POST are methods of HTTP request. 
You can find out which method your request is by calling

```
public String getMethod();
```

on your request.
You might also want to take a look on the description of HTTP protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol
The difference between parameters being sent in GET in and POST method is that in GET request parameters are sent in query string, and in POST request these are sent in request body.

Comment: Thank you, but I understand what methods are. By saying "GET parameter" I mean those which are given after "?" in path (GET /index?a=123 here "a" is GET parameter which equals "123") and by saying POST parameter I mean those which are given in request body. Sometimes it happens so that request /index?a=123 has also "b=456" in body. And in my case I need to have all POST parameters without any GET parameters.

Comment: @vlad-lezhnin is correct, there's no distinction between the location of a parameter, query string or post form, both are parameters, both are merged into the parameter list per the servlet spec.  The whole parameter concept is a convenience for developers.  Your need to know which is which means you have an advanced case, and you should ignore the whole .getParameter() layer and write your own POST request body parsing, and URL query section parsing. (good luck)

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt thanks, I understood it about five minutes after I worte my comment and googled a little more. Fortunately, Jetty provides easy ways to read POST body and parse query strings with UrlEncoded. But I still think it would be very convenient to have `getPOSTParameter(name)` and `getGETParameter(name)` like, for instance, PHP has `$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays.